# How upload image Using HttpClient in .netCore

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

I want to using HttpClient to upload an Image.

In the developper tools I find the sending data.

```
PUT /upload/temporary/24ccf835-fe35-4bbf-adbd-d6077158d5e3.jpg%0A HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 07cda27c-e534-4dfe-824f-c699eaf13440
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 101468
```

this is postman out put:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://example.com/upload/temporary/24ccf835-fe35-4bbf- 
adbd-d6077158d5e3.jpg");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
request.AddParameter("image/jpeg", "<file contents here>", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

how can i attach file by addParameter in httpClient?

Comment: Do you need an upload method like in this post? https://brokul.dev/sending-files-and-additional-data-using-httpclient-in-net-core

Comment: no, i want to post binary image , in restSharp image send by parameter ,